# Получить минимальное значение из классов

Tags: javascript

Есть несколько `div class="price-tab-main-row"`. Каждый имеет цифровое значение (`Number`). Как высчитать самое минимальное значение из них и вставить в `div class="to_price"`?

```js
const price1 = document.Element.className('div.price-tab-main-row div:nth-child(4)');
const doublePrice = document.querySelector('.to_price');
const childNode = price1.childNodes[0];
const childClone = childNode.cloneNode(true);
doublePrice.appendChild(childClone);
```

```css
.to_price {
  font-weight: bold
}
```

```html
<div class="to_price"></div>

<div class="price-title">
  <div class="price-tab-main-row">
    <div>Имп</div>
    <div>1 100 </div>
    <div>27 240 </div>
    <div>427 </div>
    <div>437 </div>
  </div>
  <div class="price-tab-main-row">
    <div>Имп</div>
    <div>800 </div>
    <div>19 811 </div>
    <div>311 </div>
    <div>318 </div>
  </div>
  <div class="price-tab-main-row">
    <div>Имп</div>
    <div>900 </div>
    <div>22 287 </div>
    <div>350 </div>
    <div>358 </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В чем проблема просто взять и сравнить их?

#### Решение

```js
const priceRows = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(`div.price-tab-main-row`)).map(element => element.children[3]); // 3 потому-что расчет дочерных объектов начинается с 0
const minPriceRow = (() => {
    let minRow = null;
    for (let index = 0, min = Infinity; index < priceRows.length; index++) {
        const row = priceRows[index];
        const price = Number.parseFloat(row.innerText);
        if (Number.isNaN(price)) {
            throw new TypeError(`can't convert content to price`);
        } else {
            if (price < min) {
                min = price;
                minRow = row;
            }
        }
    }
    if (minRow) {
        return minRow;
    } else {
        throw new ReferenceError(`can't reach the element with min price`);
    }
})();
document.querySelector(`div.to_price`)?.appendChild(minPriceRow.cloneNode(true));
```

Comment: Ваш код работает верно, только высчитывает максимальное значение ) Подскажите, как быть если нужно сравнить из 'div.price-tab-main-row div:nth-child(4)' ?

Comment: @АннаМатвеева вопрос прочитал невнимательно. Исправил)

Comment: @АннаМатвеева то есть вы хотите искать начиная с 4-ого или искать в 4-ом элементе?

Comment: eccs0103, в четвертом.

Comment: В `Parent.querySelector()` можно искать все как в селекторах css. Для поиска в 4-ом элементе пишите: `div.price-tab-main-row:nth-child(4)`.

Comment: Можете посмотреть еще раз (отредактированный) вопрос?

Comment: @АннаМатвеева так вам нужно в каждом 4-ом элементе в каждой строке! Взгляните на подправленный ответ.

Comment: Спасибо! Очень помогли )

Answer (score 0):

1. Использовать `querySelectorAll` для выборки всех элементов с нужным классом
2. Цилом пробежать по ним и поместить данные в массив (не забыв преобразовать значение в виде строки в число). Данные брать посредством `textContent`
3. Можно использовать метод **[sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)** на массиве и отсортировать по возрастанию.
4. Взять первый элемент из отсортированного массива
5. Вставить данное значение в `to_price`

Answer (score 0):

Можно что-то такое сделать..

```js
document.querySelector('.to_price').innerHTML = Math.min(...[...document.querySelectorAll('.price-tab-main-row')].map(e =>e.innerHTML))
```

```css
.to_price {
  font-weight: bold
}
```

```html
<div class="to_price"></div>

<div class="price-tab-main-row">2</div>
<div class="price-tab-main-row">1</div>
<div class="price-tab-main-row">3</div>
<div class="price-tab-main-row">4</div>
```